# Access $key from object returned from firebase

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an object downloaded from firebase which is of type Bug (Custom type). However, when I tried to console log the output with the following code

```
console.log('bug',this.bug);
```

I get the following result. It is what I expected where I can go on and do things like

```
console.log('company', this.bug.companyName)
```

However, I want to get that key value as well. Howe can I do that? I tried to do

```
console.log('company', this.bug.key)
console.log('company', this.bug.$key)
```

and both of them does not work

[image: output]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to run

```
console.log('company', this.bug["$key"])
```

remember property lookup on objects is either

```
obj.someKey // or
obj["someKey"]
```

Comment: javascript 101. Cant believe I forgot about this. Is there a way to make .key work?

Comment: I must admit I am surprised that neither `key` nor `$key` work. if it were `keys` I could understand as this is a default prop of objects. So no I dont know why you cant get that in your described way

Comment: wait this is Typescript. could it be that you have to do `obj.key("key")`